# Android: Date Picker Dialog Fragment: A lot of calls for Garbage Collection

Tags: android

this is my small program to test out date picker dialogs.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button bSelectDate;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bSelectDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSelectDate);
    bSelectDate.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DateDialogFragment date = new DateDialogFragment();
    date.setCallBack(onDate);
    date.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

}

OnDateSetListener onDate = new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);



        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};
```

}

DateDialogFragment.java

```
public class DateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

Calendar cal;
OnDateSetListener onDateSet;
private int year,month,day;

public void setCallBack(OnDateSetListener onDateSet)
{
    this.onDateSet = onDateSet;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), onDateSet, year, month, day);
}
```

}

The program functions correctly however
The problem is, as soon as the button is pressed, LogCat reports a number of calls for Garbage Collection such as GC_CONCURRENT freed, GC_FOR_ALLOC freed, GREF has increased to 201. etc. 
This has concerned me, is there a way I can reduce the number of garbage collection with this small program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error, but an information that Garbage collector has run.

If you are seeing a lot of those, it might mean that you are making many allocations or have little memory. You should try to improve your program's memory performance.

There is a good source information about investigating RAM consumption in Android:

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

There is also a document about general strategies for managing your memory consumption in Android:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Android DDMS, which is part of Android development tools in eclipse, has very useful tools that you can use for profiling and memory allocation tracking.

The below screenshot highlights some of these tools (all under DDMS), some tools need to be activated by clicking the corresponding button in the left panel (highlighted in red) and then you can see the values (some with graphs) in the right panel by selecting the tab you want to watch (highlighted in Blue)

Heap and Allocation Tracker will be very useful in your case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will check these out